# How to download blobs from azure storage via node js to local storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have followed [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs#download-blobs) for downloading blobs, but it downloads blob with metadata and properties. What I need to do is download blob file as it is from azure storage to local file system with node js. *Please note that my blob storage is private.*

Below is the code I have as of now

```
    const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
    const { v1: uuidv1} = require('uuid'); 
    async function main() {
        console.log('Azure Blob storage v12 - JavaScript quickstart sample');
        // Quick start code goes here
        const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;
        const containerName = process.env.CONTAINER_NAME;
    
        // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
        // Get a reference to a container
        const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(process.env.BLOB_NAME);
        const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
        console.log('\nDownloaded blob content...');
        console.log('\t', await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody));
    }
    async function streamToString(readableStream) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks = [];
        readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
        chunks.push(data.toString());
        });
        readableStream.on("end", () => {
        resolve(chunks.join(""));
        });
        readableStream.on("error", reject);
        });
   }
    main().then(() => console.log('Done')).catch((ex) => console.log(ex.message))
```

Comment: I don’t see any download code in your post.

Comment: added in code for download, I am using the download code from azure documentation. But this code is downloading blob and converting it to steam. I need to download raw blob from azure and save it to local file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the blob content to your local file system, you can simply use [`downloadToFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobclient-downloadtofile) method.

Essentially change the following line of code:

```
const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
```

to

```
const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.downloadToFile('local-file-path');
```

You would also not need `streamToString` method so you can safely delete that.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Mantri, thanks for sharing the solution, This works fine. But I get an error while saving the file seen as below - 

```[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\xx'] {
[1]   errno: -4068,
[1]   code: 'EISDIR',
[1]   syscall: 'open',
[1]   path: 'C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Roaming\\xx'
[1] }```

I'm using ```app.getPath('userData')``` as my path to store the file that im downloading.
```fs.writeFileSync``` on the same path works perfectly fine